# Binance websocket realtime plot without blocking code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, websocket, real-time-updates, binance

I am trying to obtain and plot real-time data from Binance (ETHUSDT) using a WebSocket. Getting the data is no problem, but I cannot get a realtime plot to work when using matplotlib.

In the code, I update the close prices each time a message is received and try to plot this data in realtime. The plot is shown on the screen but blocks further code execution. I have to manually close the plot for the next message to be received.

My question is: how can I plot the data in realtime without blocking the code?

```
import websocket, json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

TRADE_SYMBOL = "ETHUSDT"
SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m"

closes = np.array([])    

#  CREATING AXIS
plt.axis([0, 1000, 0, 1])

def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes
    message = json.loads(message)

    candle = message['k']
    close = candle['c']
    closes = np.append(closes, float(close))

    # PLOTTING HERE
    plt.plot(closes)
    plt.show()


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib needs to run the GUI on the main thread.

You can setup the websocket connection on a background thread.

#### Imports

```py
import json
import threading
import websocket
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
```

#### Realtime updates to data in background

Run the websocket data changes in a thread.

```py
TRADE_SYMBOL = "ETHUSDT"
SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m"
closes = np.array([])

def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes
    message = json.loads(message)
    candle = message['k']
    close = candle['c']
    closes = np.append(closes, float(close))

def wsthread(closes):
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever()

t = threading.Thread(target=wsthread, args=(closes,))
t.start()
```

#### Animated plot

Now, animate changes to the `closes` array.

Refer to documentation for [matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html?highlight=funcanimation#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation).

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 3000])
x= np.arange(100)
y=[np.nan] * 100
line, = ax.plot(x, y)

def animate(i):
    global y
    # shift left to most recent 100 closing prices
    y[:len(closes)] = closes[-100:]
    line.set_ydata(y)
    return line,

def init():
    line.set_ydata([np.nan] * 100)
    return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, interval=20,
    init_func=init,
    blit=True
)

plt.show()
```